# Run specific code on execution of up and down methods of a migration in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I've a Laravel application which has a `users` table with around 5000 records. The table has a column `name` which needs to be replaced with `first_name` and `last_name`.

With a simple migration script I updated the schema and wrote a simple artisan command to split name into first and last and restored in DB.

Now by rolling back the migration I lose the `last_name` column along with the data. What I'm looking for is that how can I run something after the execution of `up` method and before `down` method.

What would be the most appropriate way to achieve this?

**Migration:**

```php
class ChangeColumnsInUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('name', 'first_name');
            $table->string('last_name')->after('name');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('first_name', 'name');
            $table->dropColumn('last_name');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: For such use case, I wouldn't recommend touching the migration at all, it's much easier to have two accessors on the User model to represent `first_name` and `last_name` from the `name`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered added the 'simple script' to the `up()` and `down()` functions of the migration itself? Something like this would work right?

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
        });

        // Fill the first_name and last_name based on the name column

        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('name');
        });
    }
```

The same can be done for the `down()` method, except the other way around.